# !!SERIOUS BUG!! Closing laptop lid open again shows flickering screen

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, amd-graphics, wayland, amd-processor

Hello everyone I'm an ***HP 245 G5 Laptop*** with following OS and HW config

- Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.3
- Kernel Version: 5.15.0-73-generic (64-bit)
- Graphics Platform: Wayland
- Processors: 4 × AMD A6-7310 APU with AMD Radeon R4
- Graphics Memory: 6.7 GiB of RAM
- Graphics Processor: KABINI

***Getting this serious error :***

[**Kubuntu 22.04 wayland laptop lid closing and opening problem**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCk4GuO-MwraQmvBOuMhxdNxFP81aQve/view?usp=sharing) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eCk4GuO-MwraQmvBOuMhxdNxFP81aQve/view?usp=sharing

Whenever I ***close my laptop lid and open it again*** then I see the weird thing as shown in the video.
The only option left to me at that time is to ***forcefully shut down the system using power button and restart it again***.
What should I do in order to get through this problem.
Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: If this post is about a serious bug, then you're on the incorrect web site for that. This is a Q&A or Ubuntu support site and **not** the bug tracker. All bug reports belong on the bug tracker, please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  This site in comparison is for support in working around issues.  Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI:   I saw no reason to resort to unclean shutdown (*power off*) in your video; I didn't see any attempt to switch to text terminal & attempt to work around issue, nor attempts to command linux kernel (*bypassing any stuck GUI/UI*) via SysRq commands etc.